# Terraform does not work input and environment variables

Tags: list, amazon-web-services, for-loop, environment-variables, terraform

I have a `glue job` in `aws`.
I made a loop.

In `variables.tf`

```
variable "list_of_jobs" {
  type = list(string)
  default = ["myjob1","myjob2","myjob3"]
}
```

In `glue.tf`

```
resource "aws_glue_job" "this" {
  for_each = toset(var.list_of_jobs)
  name     = each.value
  role_arn = var.role_arn

  command {
    name = "pythonshell"
    python_version = 3
    script_location = "s3://mybucket/${each.value}/run.py"
  }
}
```

In `main.tf`

```
variable "region" {}
variable "list_of_jobs" {}

module "my_glue" {
  source = "../terraform-glue"
  region = var.region
  list_of_jobs = var.list_of_jobs
}
```

This loop works fine, and I have 3 `glue jobs` after execution of `terraform apply`.
The problem, when I am trying to make:

```
export TF_VAR_list_of_jobs='["myjob1","myjob2","myjob3"]'
```

In this case, when I am making `terraform apply`, I am receiving this:

```
Error: Invalid function argument

  on ../terraform-glue/glue.tf line 2, in resource "aws_glue_job" "this":
   2:   for_each = toset(var.list_of_jobs)
    |----------------
    | var.list_of_jobsis "[\"myjob1\",\"myjob2\",\"myjob3\"]"

Invalid value for "v" parameter: cannot convert string to set of any single
type.
```

Input variables, does not work too. Only variable from `variables.tf`. Could You help me please ? I am trying to resolve this during all night.

Comment: did you try with:

`terraform apply -var='list_of_jobs=["my-job2","my-job2"]'`

Just to make sure that it works this way, maybe tf does not like a quote or something

Comment: yes, I did. The same result. I am in a shock, why it does not work ?

Comment: terraform version?

Comment: 13.5 version. On of the latest.

Comment: can you try something older, like 0.13.1 or even 0.12.26? Remember to use a different state backend

Comment: In the examples you shared you seem to have two declarations of `variable "list_of_jobs"`, only one of which has a type constraint. Terraform would normally generate an error if you have two declarations of the same variable, so I think there must be something in your configuration you aren't showing. Can you share a complete configuration example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not work because you need to **provide type constrain** for your complex variable if you want to pass it though env variables:

```
variable "list_of_jobs" {
  type    = list(string)
  default = ["myjob1","myjob2","myjob3"]
}
```

Comment: `variable "list_of_jobs" {
  type    = list(string)
}`
I did this, but in a result `list of string required`

Comment: @Piduna So provide the list of strings, this is what your `list_of_jobs` is.

Comment: @Piduna You can also drop the string from type, and just use `type    = list` if you want. Nevertheless, type must be present for complex types, as your list.

Comment: `The given value is not suitable for child module variable "list_of_job" defined`
In my variables.tf
`variable "list_of_jobs" {
  type = list
#  default = ["myjob1","myjob2","myjob3"]
}
`
In my main.tf

`
variable "list_of_jobs" {}
`
I am making `terraform apply -var='list_of_jobs=["myjob1","myjob2"]'`

Comment: @Piduna Which "child module variable"? You don't have any modules in your question.

Comment: let me update in answer full picture. Ok ?

Comment: I updated question. Could You look please.

Comment: @Piduna Your `variable "list_of_jobs" {}` also needs type.